Python aiohttp - how to close a session?
I am totally new to async.  I'm having trouble closing connections when trying to make async requests.  Here is my code:
def async_aiohttp_get_all(self, urls):
    """
    performs asynchronous get requests
    """
    async def get_all(urls):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector_owner=False) as session:
            async def fetch(url):
                async with session.get(url) as response:
                    #return await response.json()
                    rtn = {"url": response.url,
                           "content": await response.text()}
                    return rtn
            rslts = await asyncio.gather(*[
                fetch(url) for url in urls
            ])
            return rslts
    # call get_all as a sync function to be used in a sync context
    return sync.async_to_sync(get_all)(urls)

The error I'm getting is:
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000024EE21F4890>, 10368.656), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000024EE21F4770>, 10368.671), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000024EE21F49B0>, 10368.687), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000024EE21F4AD0>, 10368.75), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000024EE2261D90>, 10369.078)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x0000024EE280C260>

I thought the solution must be to add await session.close(), which I tried on the line before return rslts but this didn't make any difference.
Anyone can help me?

the with keyword will gracefully close your client connection, so the problem could possible be with connector_owner=False remove it and let see what happens.

This turned out to be exactly the problem.  Thank you so much!  Solved :)

Hey no worries , always happy to help :)

The with keyword will gracefully close your client connection, so the problem could possible be with connector_owner=False remove it.
 async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async def fetch(url):
       async with session.get(url) as response:
             #return await response.json()
             rtn = {"url": response.url,"content": await response.text()}
             return rtn


